# Is asking for the moral of a story on topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm conflicted about how to interpret the finale of Avatar the Last Airbender and I want to ask others what they think the message of the finale is supposed to be. Is this on topic?

Comment: "Good triumphs over evil" not enough for ya?

Answer (score 13):

#### Questions like this can be OK, but please try not to make it too opinion-based.

There are already questions on the site which amount to "what does the ending of this story mean/signify". Even if they're not specifically about the *moral*, answering questions of this form does often involve describing the moral of the story.

- [What does the end of "Nine billion names of God" signify?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102956/31394)
- [Demystifying Zelazny's "Lord of Light"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/51915/31394)

The key thing to do when asking a question like this is to **try to make it reasonably answerable**. We close "primarily opinion-based" questions, and where to draw the line between "*primarily* opinion-based" and "partly opinion-based but not too much" is something that different people are going to have different opinions on. Some subjectivity is OK, but it should always be [Good Subjective and not Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). The key difference is in the answers: Good Subjective questions **can be answered by drawing upon objective evidence**; Bad Subjective questions invite discussion and opinion. These guidelines have been codified in the [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

Answer (score 9):

### It's fine if you ask for in-universe perspective or author intention

We have a tag for [morality and ethics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/morality/info) questions, they are clearly on-topic here. That said, I think this questions should not be an invitation to debate personal moral perspectives on a work of fiction.

If you check the most well received morality questions they ask for:

1. In-universe moral perspective:

   - [Were there any "good" Separatist military leaders?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116889/were-there-any-good-separatist-military-leaders)
   - [Did any Jedi question the ethics of having a clone army?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143111/did-any-jedi-question-the-ethics-of-having-a-clone-army)
   - [Has Captain America ever been completely in the wrong?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79956/has-captain-america-ever-been-completely-in-the-wrong)
2. In-universe moral rules

   - [What's the difference between the Light side and the Dark side of the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/whats-the-difference-between-the-light-side-and-the-dark-side-of-the-force)
   - [What exactly is the Ancients' policy regarding intervention?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171485/what-exactly-is-the-ancients-policy-regarding-intervention)
3. Authors perspective:

   - [James Potter vs. Severus Snape - any official word?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110147/james-potter-vs-severus-snape-any-official-word)
   - [Word of God on Tuvix's Murder](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95729/word-of-god-on-tuvixs-murder)

These kind of questions, which have a definitive answer and don't invite POB answers, are completely on-topic.